# How to write the following equation in Matlab or Mathematica?

Tags: matlab, math, wolfram-mathematica

I have the following equation:
[image]

Where N^{optim} and K are my variables and M and S are just constants. I want to do some processing to this function like maximizing it, solving it for some values. So I need to write it in terms of the symbolic variables in Matlab. But I don't know how the summation for the symbolic variables. Any help, recommendation, comment is highly appreciated.
If any one knows how to do it in mathematica, or other software that might help as well but I would prefer Matlab and Mathematica.

Thank you.

Comment: Is S another constant?

Comment: yes @andy mcevoy S is another constant

Answer (score 1):

```
In[1]:= Binomial[no - m, m]/Binomial[no, m] Sum[Binomial[s, i] Binomial[m, no]^i
(1 - Binomial[m, no])^(s - i), {i, 0, k}]

Out[1]= -(((1 - Binomial[m, no])^(-1 - k + s)*Binomial[-m + no, m]*(-(((1 -
Binomial[m, no])^(-1))^s*(1 - Binomial[m, no])^k) + ((1-Binomial[m, no])^(-1))^s*
(1 - Binomial[m, no])^k*Binomial[m, no] + Binomial[m, no]^(1 + k)*
Binomial[s, 1 + k]*Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1 + k - s, 2 + k, Binomial[m, no]/
(-1 + Binomial[m, no])]))/Binomial[no, m])
```

Check that result carefully before you depend on it.

Comment: Thank you very much I will run it out tomorrow and tell you about it.

Comment: IF all your variables are Integers then you can get a somewhat simpler result by evaluating   $Assumptions= no \\[Element] Integers && m \\[Element] Integers && s \\[Element] Integers && k \\[Element] Integers;